# What should I do before removing a DOM element in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I remember hearing about needing to destroy the scope on an element before removing it from the DOM. But I'm not exactly sure how that is done.

So, it just so happens that I have a directive that removes an element from the DOM. A stripped down version would look like:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app').directive('remove', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.children().remove();
                element.remove();
            }
        }
    }]);
}());
```

A simple and unpractical example would be something like
`<my-directive-with-isolated-scope remove></my-directive-with-isolated-scope>`

I can remove the element, but it doesn't seem like the scope gets destroyed, which I believe would create a memory leak right? I also set an `$interval` in the directive's controller (the one with the isolated scope), where I set a console message to go out as a test. And I can see that when it's removed from the DOM, it still logs out a console message at the set interval.

Would I be modifying something in the directive above in order to remove the element properly?

Answer (score 2):

A couple experiments for you to try with element/scope destruction:

You can do a test to see when the scope gets destroyed like this:

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    console.log('Scope Destroyed!');
});
```

You can also test for element being destroyed:

```
element.on('$destroy', function(){
    console.log('Element Destroyed!');
});
```

*(Please see **Events** section of [angular.element docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element))*

Now, about the interval:

The `$interval` will run until you `$interval.cancel()` it, whether the scope exists or not (unless the callback is some function bound to `scope` in which case the callback may turn undefined and I'm not exactly sure how `$interval` handles that).

If your directive is running an `$interval` function, you might have something like:

```
var count = 0;
var timer = 
    $interval( function doingStuff () {
        console.log( count + ' seconds ...' );
    }, 1000 );

scope.$on('$destroy', function cleanup () {
    $interval.cancel( timer );
});
```

About needing to manually destroy scopes:

If you manually create a scope via `var myScope = $scope.$new();` it is your responsibility to destroy it via `myScope.$destroy();`.  I would say this is a more advanced usage and I can't think of any really common reasons to manually create a new scope.  (Perhaps if your directive was to create an element and `$compile` it with a brand new scope)

Answer (score 0):

If the element is generated from the scope you should destroy it be removing the scope data and letting angular re-render it, not using a DOM operation. The scope data isn't related to DOM element itself, the element is just what gets rendered based on the scope. So removing an element won't have any effect on the scope variables.

You should not be using a directive to do this; Change or remove the value from the scope instead.

Answer (score 0):

Directives such as `ng-view`, `ng-if`, `ng-repeat`, `ng-include`, etc. that add elements to the DOM, first create a child scope, and use the `$compile` service to compile and link those elements to that child scope before attaching them to the DOM. Those compiled elements are linked to the created child scope. When those directives subsequently remove those elements, they also destroy the child scope.

To create a child scope:

```
var childScope = scope.$new();
```

To destroy that child scope:

```
childScope.$destroy();
```

For more information, see [AngularJS rootScope.scope API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).